# change orientation in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I set Orientation to AutoRotation in originally , Allowed LandscapeRight and LandscapeLeft.

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait

Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation
```

When I change Screen.orientation to Portrait and resume to Autorotation, the screen keep portrait until I rotation the phone.

This problem only happen on android device.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you think that it is natural behaviour? you set orientation to portrait, phone goes to portrait, then you change to autorotation, now this will change orientation according to how you are holding device. it won't force the app to go to allowed orientations for autorotation. It will stay there unless you rotate it. You need to explicitly set the orientation to specific value if you want it to change immediately. [Read More](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

**1**.Change to portrait.

**2**.When you decide to change back to AutoRotation, do it.

**3**.Read the current orientation(`DeviceOrientation`). Convert it into `ScreenOrientation` then assign it to the screen orientation.

***Note***: You shouldn't read the current screen orientation with `Screen.orientation`. This is done with `Input.deviceOrientation`.

Those three steps put in code:

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation;
Screen.orientation = DeviceToScreenOrientation(Input.deviceOrientation);
```

The `DeviceToScreenOrientation` function that converts `Input.deviceOrientation`/`DeviceOrientation` enum to `Screen.orientation`/`ScreenOrientation` enum.

```
ScreenOrientation DeviceToScreenOrientation(DeviceOrientation dvceOr)
{
    ScreenOrientation scrOr = ScreenOrientation.Unknown;
    switch (dvceOr)
    {
        case DeviceOrientation.Unknown:
            scrOr = ScreenOrientation.Unknown;
            break;

        case DeviceOrientation.Portrait:
            scrOr = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            break;

        case DeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
            scrOr = ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;
            break;

        case DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
            scrOr = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
            break;

        case DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            scrOr = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight;
            break;

        //Don't know What Enum to use. Implement to match your need
        case DeviceOrientation.FaceUp:
            //scrOr = ?
            break;

        case DeviceOrientation.FaceDown:
            //scrOr = ?
            break;
    }
    return scrOr;
}
```

**You may need to switch step #2 and #3**.